# CSS child selectors and their rendering speed in general

Tags: css

I just discovered that my way of writing CSS is not efficient at all. That it is least recommended way. I'm bitting myself for not familiarising with best practices before!

I've a project I'm working on, and I finished header and footer. Project is complicated with allot of fly out menus, so it took me some time to just create html markup and style it. I'm over 600 lines in CSS.

Now I'm thinking to braze it all and start from zero with new best methods in my head!

But than I wonder if it will make any difference?

I've these:

```
.page_menu ul li a:hover, #page_menu_fixed ul.nav li a:hover
#page_menu_fixed ul.cats ul.flyout_first > li > .flyout_search > .search_field
```

Not allot of them, but in few spots I use this overly long selectors :S What do you think?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/rendering

Comment: Optimizing css selector performance is likely one of the last things you should think about. Only do this when you are 100% sure you need to. (Run performance tests and find the bottlenecks)

Comment: Stop biting yourself. Now: what's your actual question?

Comment: It might make a difference on slower devices (i.e. mobile devices), but probably not worth your time.  Probably good to take an optimized approach from the beginning on new projects...

Comment: @PaulD.Waite It would appear his question is whether it will make a performance difference to scrap and rewrite his CSS selectors.  Was that not clear?

Comment: @landons: not super-clear. Re-write how? It's a pretty vague question as it stands.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Let's give the OP the benefit of the doubt before we close this :).  I think it's a valid question whether it's worth it to optimize CSS selectors for performance.

Comment: @Adrift The inefficiency of certain selectors is overexaggerated:  http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/03/10/performance-impact-of-css-selectors/

Comment: @landons: your phrasing of the question ("whether it's worth it to optimize CSS selectors for performance") sounds a bit too general too me, and it's not quite what the OP asked.

Comment: @Sandro Could you revise the question to be more specific?  I think this could be constructive and reopened..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just remember browsers reading selectors from right to left and the more specific you are or lesser elements the browser need to "find" the faster your CSS is. overall css most time is not the problem of rendering speed. and about 600 lines of CSS are like what 10-20 ms ? concentrate on server speed, images, and big javascripts.